# MYSQL:Looking for equivalent of Perl's "regex" =~ s/e/i/g => rigix in a MySQL Select

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

Can I match and replace a text pattern in a MYSQL select?

---

**EDIT**
For now it looks like the answer is: **Can't be done,
since you can't capture what was matched** (from [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95589/eric)'s answer / comments). For now I will look into adding a lookup table.

---

Simplified example:

The MySQL table Coleridge holds many strings like:

```
text
------------------------------------
In_Xanadu_did_Kubla_Khan
A_stately_pleasure_dome_decree
Where_Alph_the_sacred_river_ran
Through_caverns_measureless_to_man
Down_to_a_sunless_sea
```

Is there a way to express the select

SELECT **text =~ s / [ ^_ ] + _ ( .* ) _ [ ^_ ] + $ / \1 /** as replaced FROM Coleridge

and get

```
replaced
________________________
Xanadu_did_Kubla
stately_pleasure_dome
Alph_the_sacred_river
caverns_measureless_to
to_a_s
```

**Please Note:**

1. The regular expression s/ / / I
   provided is much less complicated
   than what the real world DB contains
2. Unfortunately I can't normalize
   the DB ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no regex way to replace anything in MySQL. You can match in MySQL based on RegEx ([`regexp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)), but that doesn't return what part is matched, just the whole column that is. But, you can use [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) like so:

```
select replace(col, 'e', 'i') from tbl
```

This will return `regex` as `rigix`.

As for your specific example, you'd have to use a combination of [`locate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
select 
    substring(col
        , locate('_', col)+1
        , locate('_', reverse(col))-(len(col)-locate('_', col)-1)) 
from tbl
```

The general rule on string manipulations/handling on the database level is: Keep it simple. RDBMS's think in sets, and that's where they shine. Pulling individual string manipulations is not in their sweet spot. As such, no RDBMS has really mature string handling functions (and there certainly isn't any consistency across the different ones). If your regex is reasonably complex, you will most likely want to just handle it on the presentation/app layer, and not in the database.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately my regex can't be expressed that easily (unless I code a convoluted mess of IF/CASE blocks six feet deep) .. I'll have a word with the DBA .. I might have to build a lookup-table.

Comment: I believe the correct answer to my question is in your comment to chao's answer: You can't capture what was matched.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.  MySQL only supports regexes for matching (`RLIKE`), not replacement.

Comment: Important to note that you can't capture what was matched, just that a column was matched.